# React Typescript MUI Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory (@emotion/is-prop-valid/dist/is-prop-valid.browser.esm.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

React typescript shows the error;

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@emotion/is-prop-valid/dist/is-prop-valid.browser.esm.jsModule build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/e/www/akshaykn/node_modules/@emotion/is-prop-valid/dist/is-prop-valid.browser.esm.js'
```

My package.json has ;

```
"dependencies": {
        "@emotion/is-prop-valid": "^1.1.1",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.1.1",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.35",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
    }
```

Any idea? Thnx.